# StoreProduct IsInUserCollection is always false

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

We have a UWP product in the Microsoft Store. The product has a number of subscription add-ons. Users make in-app purchases of subscription add-ons.
**EDIT** Our code is cobbled from Microsoft Docs [Enable subscription add-ons for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#cancellations)

```
StorePurchaseResult result = await product.RequestPurchaseAsync();
if (result.Status == StorePurchaseStatus.Succeeded)
```

The result returns `StorePurchaseStatus.Succeeded`. Microsoft has taken the user's money for the subscription add-on. All good so far.

We qet a product list like this

```
string[] productKinds = { "Durable" };
List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);

StoreProductQueryResult queryResult = await storeContext.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(filterList);
productList = queryResult.Products.Values.ToList();
```

Then iterate through

```
foreach (StoreProduct storeProduct in products)
{
    if (storeProduct.IsInUserCollection)
...
}
```

but `storeProduct.IsInUserCollection` always returns false. Microsoft has accepted payment for the add-on but not added it to the user's collection of products, so we cannot verify they have paid for the add-on.

Where did we go wrong?

**EDIT 2** Following a suggestion from @lukeja I ran this method

```
async Task CheckSubsAsync()
{
    StoreContext context = context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
    StoreAppLicense appLicense = await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();

    foreach (var addOnLicense in appLicense.AddOnLicenses)
    {
        StoreLicense license = addOnLicense.Value;
        Debug.WriteLine($"license.SkuStoreId {license.SkuStoreId}");
    }
}
```

This outputs only a single add-on. The free add-on. We have 16 add-ons only one of which is free.

Why aren't any of our paid add-on subscriptions returned?

**EDIT 3** `appLicense.AddOnLicenses` only includes add-on licenses for the current user, not all add-ons for the app. The code sample provided by @lukeja works as expected when run within the context of the user who paid the subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using that method. The way I'm currently doing it in my app and the way that Microsoft's documentation suggests is like this...

```
private async Task<bool> CheckIfUserHasSubscriptionAsync()
{
    StoreAppLicense appLicense = await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();

    // Check if the customer has the rights to the subscription.
    foreach (var addOnLicense in appLicense.AddOnLicenses)
    {
        StoreLicense license = addOnLicense.Value;

        if (license.IsActive)
        {
            // The expiration date is available in the license.ExpirationDate property.
            return true;
        }
    }

    // The customer does not have a license to the subscription.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @lukeja I've edited my question to show a reference to Microsoft docs where I sourced the code we use. We have 16 add-ons and the code we currently use returns all 16 which we iterate through. The code you provide only returns a single add-on from the 16 add-ons we have for this app in the store.